# Closing full screen windows with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am reading files from a directory and want to display them one at a time full screen to another display. Then I take a picture using my webcam. However, using setWindowProperty(), only the first image goes full screen. Subsequent images are not fit to the screen and appear with a title tab at the top. Also, the first image that I display is repeatedly displayed full screen as I iterate through the rest of the images. Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import os
import time

directory = "Desktop/6163ImgSet2/"
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    ##create window
    cv2.namedWindow("window", cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv2.setWindowProperty("window",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN) 
    image = cv2.imread(directory + filename)
    ###display image
    cv2.imshow("window", image)
    ##take picture
    check, frame = webcam.read()
    cv2.imwrite(filename = "Desktop/nc_" + filename, img = frame)
    cv2.waitKey(5000)
    ###close window
    cv2.destroyWindow("window")
webcam.release()
```

Comment: In imshow use "window"

Comment: That's a bit better, but now only odd images show up full screen (i.e. 1st, 3rd iteration). Even images show up in a tiny window. Any thoughts?